# help, i've lost my .vdi file for my virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

i seem to have lost the .vdi file for my virtual box virtual machine. I am pretty sure i haven't just deleted it. Just to check no one else had i checked the recycle bin and it wasn't there.

i don't have a back up of that part of my system, windows back-up wasn't working on it (i think because the file was too big) so i changed by back-up settings to not include it (dumb idea).

It's just gone missing, any ideas how, or better yet, any ideas where?

If i did accidentally delete it through the virtual box interface would it be in the recycling bin?

Comment: When did you lose it? What were you doing for the few days before and after? Installed/uninstalled any software? Any unusual events like power outages or lightning storms?

Comment: Just before i noticed the problem i deleted a lot of stuff from the download folder. When it said it couldn't find a drive, I thought what i'd deleted was just the .iso of software i'd already installed, so i did a bit of reckless ok clicking. But then the VM wouldn't start. I tried restoring what i thought were the relevant files and that didn't help. Then i restored the virtual-box user settings etc. through windows back-up and tried again, and i noticed the missing file was actually the .vdi for the whole machine. I think it went missing before that though, i don't think that caused it.

Comment: i can't think of anything unusual i've done between now and the last time the Vm worked properly, all i can think is windows just glitches in very large files?

Answer (score 1):

Use WinDirStat to see where big files are hiding.
If you cannot locate it there, I am not sure how to proceed.

http://windirstat.info/

Comment: will it find files i can't see in windows explorer or viewing folder contents in the command line window? i don't think files can just run away, so it would be where i left it or recycle bin? could this see it if it's there but windows just isn't recognizing it?

Comment: Hmm I am not sure, you could try it out, it only takes a few seconds, it visually shows you what files take up how much space.. its a great tool for all sorts of things